# "Failed to start session" Openbox

Tags: login, lightdm, openbox

I'm trying to create a custom ISO so I don't have to always reinstall openbox.

I removed ubuntu-session and installed openbox. Booting the ISO works, but when I boot it up after installationf, it says "failed to start session" in LightDM. Even if I don't remove ubuntu-session, it does the same and I have to actually choose a session in LightDM.

I have a .dmrc included by default in the home folder with openbox set. The installation seems to overwrite it with "ubuntu," but even if I get int a tty and change it back, it still fails to start the session... I tried including a lightdm.conf in /etc/lightdm, but it doesn't seem to fix the problem either. Maybe it's in /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d?

Thanks a lot to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel really silly now. I had tried creating a custom lightdm.conf in /etc/lightdm/, but I had the session set as "openbox-session."

For anyone out there reading this, the name must match the file in /usr/share/xsessions. openbox is not like gnome-session, ubuntu-session, etc. It is just openbox.

Answer (score 1):

I am also trying a Ubuntu Server + Openbox configuration. I have bumped into lightdm "Failed to start session" :-) thanks to your posting I manage to work around it... i think... what i have done: i have copied `/usr/share/xsession/openbox` file to `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf/openbox` and I have created inside `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` a `50-myconfig.conf` (`sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf/50-myconfig.conf`) file (based on the info from here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM) with the following content:

> [SeatDefaults]
>   user-session=openbox

now I manage to login into openbox